# How to prevent evaluation without simplification?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, evaluation

I am trying to compute a sequence of terms, which have a form similar to $g(z)$ at different points $z$. For $z$ close to 0, I have observed that the terms are evaluated as 0/0 (indeterminate form) instead of full simplification first, and then substitution, which would give the correct answer. I have quoted here, a snippet of code that represents the issue I encounter.

```
f[ z_] = Sin[z];
g[ z_] := FullSimplify[f[ z]/f[ z]];

Limit[g[z], z -> 0]
(* 1 *)

g[0]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[74]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
> During evaluation of In[74]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
> Indeterminate
> ```

How can I ensure that the full simplify is performed before  evaluation is done? Thankyou.

Comment: you defined `g` to take two arguments `g[n_, z_]` . But you are calling it using one argument `g[z]`? How did it work for you?

Comment: I have just edited my post to make the correction. It was a residual typo from simplifying my original problem. Thankyou for pointing it out.

Comment: If you use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, it's fine: `g[ z_] = FullSimplify[f[ z]/f[ z]]` evaluates directly to 1 (notice the lack of colon in front of the equal signs). I see a lot of recommendations saying to default to `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for function definitions, but it's really not necessary once you're careful about your global variable declarations.

Comment: I don't think your question is well-stated. Your "real" code can't possibly be `FullSimplify[f[ z]/f[ z]]`, and this is such a special case that solutions to this special case probably won't generalize to your "real" code. Is the problem really evaluation order, or is it a matter of accuracy? You said "For z close to 0", and that's what made me think this is an accuracy issue.

Comment: +1 to @march for suggesting just `Set`.  You can also verify it's doing exactly what they're suggesting by comparing the [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) between using `Set` and `SetDelayed`.  I use this trick for immediate evaluation and assignment of functions like this all the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is just evaluation order. One way to workaround it could be

```
f[z_] = Sin[z]
g[z_] := Module[{x}, FullSimplify[f[x]/f[x]] /. x -> z]
```

And now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There might be other ways.

Comment: This process seems to be very slow as opposed to direct evaluation to the point that it is not feasible in my original problem. Is the rate limiting process the use of FullSimplify?

Comment: @sai  FullSimplify is known to be very slow!  (it tries many many things more compared to Simplify). Try with only Simplify? in my codes I always try `Simplify` first and if that fails, only then try FullSimplify.

Comment: I have tried Simplify and it is still very slow.

Comment: @sai well if Simplify is also slow, then this issue has nothing really to do with the above code I have, right? I am just using your code and you had Simplify in there. You question was about evaluation order and not why Simplify is slow or not.  May be you could ask separate question on that if you want.

Comment: I have asked another related question where I think I can circumvent simplify. Thankyou for your suggestion. I will still keep this question open in case there are workarounds to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[z_] := Sin[z];
g[z_] := f[z]/f[z]

g[z]

(* 1 *)

Limit[g[z], z -> 0]

(* 1 *)
```

??